# HttpWebRequest: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, multithreading, proxy, httpwebrequest

I develop client app which connects to the server and fetches different information from it. It is multithreaded app. When I start it with a few threads it works perfect. 
Until it start throwing an exception with the following message:

"Unable to connect to the remote server"

I've used TCPView and cannot find anything about my client app. So when it starts returning "Unable to Connect" it doesn't even OPEN any http connections...

How can I figure out why it doesn't open connection?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I'm using in Multiple threads to fecth page content:

```
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
        Stream resStream = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        string res = "";            
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            if (cookies_ == null)
            {
                cookies_ = new CookieContainer();
            }
            request.Timeout = timeoutVal_;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeoutVal_ * 2;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            if (bUseCookies)
            {
                request.CookieContainer = cookies_;
            }

            // execute the request
            response = (HttpWebResponse)
                request.GetResponse();

            resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            res = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(siteToken + " " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
                response.Close();

            if (resStream != null)
                resStream.Close();

            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        return res;
```

After a couple minutes threads getting into cycle with Timeout Exception or Unable to connect to Server.

The strange thing that if I start Fiddler, connections get reactivated and threads continue working for some time. How does Fiddler fix that problem?

Comment: Snarky answer: that is what the debugger is for. Real answer: If it cannot connect to the server then they won't appear OPEN in TCPView. We'll at least need to see some code to help you figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You may be connecting internet through a proxy check your IE lan settings. from c# you need to add proxy settings.

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
                    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888", true);
                    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "ADomain");
                    request.Proxy = proxy;
                    request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

                    request.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 5;
                    request.Method = method;
                    request.Headers.Add("DAUTH", dauth);request.GetResponse();
```